# How can I authenticate modules, only allowing 'approved' modules to be used?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a WPF application, using Prism to allow for modules to be used. I search a directory for all modules and load any modules in that directory.

I want to provide a way for users to add modules they create, but I also only want modules that are approved to be added to the application. How could I go about this?

I thought about some sort of private/public key authentication, but if someone made a module, got it approved and had a key added, then I have no way of preventing modification to that module after the key has been added...if that makes sense.

Comment: It would be our development team that would give the 'approval'. Ultimately, what we want is the ability for end users to be able to create custom add-ins, but we want to make sure the add-ins they create do not adversely affect the system. 

The purpose of the application is to allow for modules, or add-ins, to be added to extend functionality without having to push out a new build of the core code.

Comment: Have you thought about versioning? What if an author of a released module (v.1.0) wants to upgrade it with version 2.0? Need for re-approval?

Comment: Since an approval is granted based on the current functionality, an update must go through a code-review to make sure the module won't have any adverse affects on the application or consumed services.

Because of this, I think any updated would need re-approval. I suppose this could get a little annoying for minor bug fixes in the  modules.